# Spring Batch System command tasklet doesn't pipe output to a file

Tags: spring-batch

In my Batch Job, I need to find a diff of an old file and new file received , and insert/update the diff records only. I created a system command tasklet for this with the diff command as below:

```
<bean id="fileDiffTasklet" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.SystemCommandTasklet" scope="step">
<property name="command" value="diff #{jobParameters['SOURCE_FILE']} #{jobParameters['PREVIOUS_FILE']} |  grep -e &apos;&lt;&apos; -e &apos;&gt;&apos; | grep -x '.\{#{jobParameters['LINE_LENGTH']}\}' > #{jobParameters['input.file.name']}"/>
<property name="timeout" value="2000000"/>
<property name="workingDirectory" value="/INBOOUND/"/>
</bean>
```

I'm piping the output to a file , so in chunk based tasklet, I read this file which contains the diff records, process and write those records alone. But system command tasklet executes but doesn't pipe the output to the file.

In this case, Can I have the commands in shell script and launch that script from System command tasklet by passing job parameters as arguments to the shell script? If this will redirect the output of script to a file, will system command tasklet wait till the completion of execution of the script? Since files are of very large size, it takes around 5 minutes to complete the diff command. So my need is that , only after the file is created, next step should get executed.

Comment: Have you confirmed the command you're executing?

Comment: @MichaelMinella: Yes, I also came to know in one of the threads, like in spring batch its not possible to pipe the output to the file directly using '>'. So i created a shell script for the command and need to pass the job parameters as arguments. Like this is where I'm bit confused on the procedure.

Comment: I am trying this command "tail -1 %s > input_footer.txt && head -n -1 %s > input_body.txt" Will it work with SystemCommandTasklet ?